# How to add marketing List to campaign using javascript in crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to add current opened campaign form to Marketing list(this marketing list form was opened from left navigation of that campaign), after providing input to marketing list form , i need to associate this marketing list to current form of campaign using java script.

please find the screen shot below for your clear reference.

Below image is an normal campaign form
[image: the below image is an campaign form]

After selecting "Marketing List" from left navigation of previous image.
And from here i need to select "Add New Marketing List".
[image]
After providing Input to Marketing list form, then if i select save and close , i will get the marketing name list in "Marketing list Associated View" in Campaign form as in next image.
[image]

But this Marketing list is not associating with the current campaign, so how to associate this with campaign. can we use javascript to associate , or can we use any ribbon buttons to associate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The relationsihp between campaign and marketing list is N:N. So the created marketing list can be used by multiple campaigns.

Comment: s thanks Jeff. But that created Marketing list in left navigation is also N:N , but its not associating

Comment: your mean is you can't see the related campaign entry in left navigation of marketing list?

Comment: yeah yes Jeff. how to relate campaign and Marketinglist